# R.java can't be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, r.java-file

i'm using eclise, my project was running very well yest. without any exceptions.
suddenly when i create a new project, an error appeared in the prev. project "R.java can't be resolved to a variable" and the sclipse suggests to import the android.R and i don't want that i want to use the projects's R.java...
when i opened gen/com/examples/myProject/ --> ***Here i should find the R.java file but i found nothing***

i read all old posts about this issue but nothing worked with me, as some suggested to:
1) Clean and Build the project,
2) check the xml file, but i don't have any errors because the application was running yest. as i said before.

so any idea??

Comment: Check out your file names. You can only use `a...z` (LOWER CASE), `0...9`, `.` and `_`

Comment: clean and build your project, if it is now working then restart your eclipse